# Generating dates to the days of a week in Python?

Tags: python, date, calendar

I need to generate a date of Monday of a week from a date (example: 2015/10/22). And generate the dates for the next days: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday.

Example in Java: (initial date = 2015/10/22)

// Monday:

```
date.set (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
```

// Add the next day (Tuesday)

```
date.add (Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

// Add the next day (Wednesday):

```
date.add (Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easier in python using timedelta function

```
import datetime

mydate = datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 22, 00, 00, 00, 00)
mymondaydate = mydate - datetime.timedelta(days=mydate.weekday())
mytuesdaydate = mymondaydate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

print(mydate)
print(mymondaydate)
print(mytuesdaydate)
```

The trick is the use of weekday() function. From documentation

> date.weekday()
>   - Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6.

So subtracting it from current date gives the date of Monday of that week

Answer (score 1):

You can set your initial date like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta    
d = datetime(2015,10,22)
```

Then if you want to get the next monday, use timedelta and datetime.weekday() (Monday is 0):

```
d + timedelta(7 - d.weekday())
datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 26, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! But your code gets the Monday of next week! I need to generate the Monday of the current week! You know how?

Comment: sure, just do `d - timedelta(d.weekday())`

Answer (score 0):

Provide another version for your question.
You can refer the document of official site: [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#module-time)

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import time

t = time.strptime('2015/10/22', '%Y/%m/%d')
old_day = date.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(t))
a_day = timedelta(days=1)
new_day = old_day + a_day

print new_day.strftime('%a')
```